# Adding Dynamic PV/C to Airflow pods

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

Problem: I have airflow on kubernetes and I have an issue with massive disk pressure on the nodes.

Context: There are about 5k pods a day and they are running a Python ETL package. I'm using airflow's KubernetesPodOperator to dynamically generate the pods via a class called "KubernetesPodGenerator".

Proposed Solution: I can use the kubernetes library to create a PV and a PVC per the code below and it should start creating pods with the PV mounted to the image. If you were to run this code you would get that behavior.

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from kubernetes import client as k8s

etl_image = "path_to_a_super_secret_image"

volume_mounts = [k8s.V1VolumeMount(name="dag-storage", mount_path='/data', sub_path=None, read_only=False)]

volumes = [
    k8s.V1Volume(
        name='dag-storage',
        persistent_volume_claim=k8s.V1PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource(claim_name='dag-storage')
    )
]


k = KubernetesPodOperator(
    name="hello-dry-run",
    image=etl_image,
    cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
    arguments=["echo", "10"],
    env_from=[
        k8s.V1EnvFromSource(
            config_map_ref=k8s.V1ConfigMapEnvSource(name="etl-config")
        )
    ],
    labels={"foo": "bar"},
    task_id="dry_run_demo",
    volumes=volumes,
    volume_mounts=volume_mounts
)

k.dry_run()
```

Problem: However, when I deploy this to airflow I do not get that mount, I get another one named "kube-api-access-1234" (1234 is variable, so that smells like programmatic creation). I do not see anything in my airflow code that would be adding this, so it must be something internal?

I also don't understand why it's overwriting the volume/mounts instead of appending them.